# Unmarshalling issue during Spring Rest Service call

Tags: spring, rest, spring-rest, xml-binding

Calling a Rest Webservice using the Spring Rest Template as follows-

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

and get the output in String format as

```
<Info xmlns="http://schemas.test.org/2009/09/Tests.new" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FirstName>FirstName</FirstName>
<LastName>LastName</LastName>
<TestGuid>Guid</TestGuid>
<TestUID>1</TestUID>
<Token>token</Token>
<TestUserID>14</TestUserID>
</Info>
```

When trying to unmarshal it to java class as follows

```
ResponseEntity<Info> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, Info.class)
```

The Info class is defined as

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Info", namespace = "http://schemas.test.org/2009/09/Tests.new")
public class Info implements Serializable{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String testGuid;
    private String testUID;
    private String token;
    private String testUserID;

    //getters and setter

}
```

get all values of the info class null like Firstname=null..

Could anyone tell what is missing?
Thanks

Comment: `@XmlElement` annotations on the different fields.

Comment: Used @XMLElement, still get values as null

Comment: Only adding `@XmlElement` you need to till which element to map to.

Comment: Thanks Deinum its wrking

Answer (score 0):

You need to map you java class like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Info", namespace = "http://schemas.test.org/2009/09/Tests.new")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Info implements Serializable{

    @XmlElement(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement(name="TestGuid")
    private String testGuid;
    @XmlElement(name="TestUID")
    private String testUID;
    @XmlElement(name="Token")
    private String token;
    @XmlElement(name="TestUserID")
    private String testUserID;

    //getters and setter

}
```